# Creating a Derived class with atributes from the same class (Node class)

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to make a derived class of nodes for AVL trees, derived from a simple node class.

```
class Node
{
    protected:
        int *value;
        Node *leftChild;
        Node *rightChild;
        friend class BST;
};

class NodeAVL : public Node
{
    private:
        int *balanceFactor;
        friend class AVL;

    public:
        ///some code
};
```

So, I need my NodeAVL's both children to be of class NodeAVL as well and I have to inherit them from the base class (it's mandatory). But as the leftChild and rightChild are declared as Node* in the base class, I can't do that directly. I don't have any ideas on how to fix this, so I need some help.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Node *` allowed to point to any `Node` descendant, including `NodeAVL`. If it does, you can just cast it to `NodeAVL *`, that’s allowed. If you’re unsure, use `dynamic_cast` instead (but `Node` would have to be polymorphic for that to work).

Comment: See [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://deviq.com/liskov-substitution-principle/)

Comment: You may employ templates: `template<typename T>class Node{T *left; T *right;};`

Comment: It gives me some errors, doesn't really work.

Comment: @Catalyst259 What errors do you get?

Comment: @Tau, it gives me the error that i'm making a Node<Node>, but Node is a template, and it would be an infinite loop like Node<Node<Node<..>>>

Comment: @Catalyst259 Can you edit your question to include that template declaration?